# Friends listing order by name Facebook sdk for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xcode5

I am using Xcode 5, iOS 7 and latest facebook sdk. I have to get the friends list in alphabetical order. Earlier I have used graph api and fql query for getting the friends list in alphabetical order as

```
NSString* fqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT uid,pic_square, name,online_presence FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY name"];
```

Now I have searched and found **FBFriendPicker** but I need to do more customisation in the friends list. 
**My doubt is** is there any way to get the **friends list in alphabetical order** as we got in previous sdks from facebook for iOS?